# Make template function for nested container

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to make a generic test function that takes a container such as list, set or vector, and returns nested container: list of lists, set of sets, vector of vectors. Non-generic functions look like this:

```
vector<vector<string>> test(vector<string>& in_container)
{
    vector<vector<string>> out_continer;

    // out_continer will be filed using values from in_container

    return out_continer;
}

list<list<int>> test(list<int>& in_container)
{
    list<list<int>> out_continer;

    // out_continer will be filed using values from in_container

    return out_continer;
}

set<set<float>> test(set<float>& in_container)
{
    set<set<float>> out_continer;

    // out_continer will be filed using values from in_container

    return out_continer;
}
```

But I dont know how to make one template test function that would be equivalent to these separate test examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vector` and `list` (and `deque`) have identical sets of template parameters and are ordinary sequences, so you can cover them with

```
template <typename T, typename U, template <typename, typename> class C>  
C<C<T, U>, std::allocator<C<T, U>>> test(C<T, U> &in)
{
  C<C<T, U>, std::allocator<C<T, U>>> out;
  // Fill it here
  return out;
}

int main() 
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv = test(v);

  std::list<int> l;
  std::list<std::list<int>> ll = test(l);
}
```

(The code is a bit convoluted since we have to specify the allocator type for the outer container explicitly, but it can probably be improved.)

Meanwhile `set` is a different kind of container (associative), which will probably require a dedicated function anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain this "template <typename T, typename U, template <typename, typename> class C>  ". What is happening here? I know normal templates, but this looks like some dark magic to me. Or some link to tutorial explaining this?

Comment: @batchtest: Templates in C++ have three kinds of parameters: type parameters (like our familiar `typename T`), non-type parameters (like `int N`) and template parameters (aka "template template paramaters"). That last parameter in my template is exactly the one of the third kind: a template template parameter `C` declared as `template <typename, typename> class C`. Such parameters are not used very often (and probably are best avoided). You can read about it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this *automatically*, but you can set up a template function if you specify the type:

```
template <typename T>
T test(typename T::value_type& in_container)
{
    T out_container;
    return out_container;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("hello");
    auto w = test<vector<vector<string>>>(v); // w is a vector<vector<string>> now
}
```